# The successive approximations

Tags: equation-solving

```
Unknowns u[n,0],u[n,1], u[n,2],u[n,3] 
u[0, 0]==0.0625`;u[0,1]==0.031249999999999997`;u[0,2]==-0.0625`;
u[0,3]==-0.03125`;u[0,4]==-0.03125`



F1 := 0.04549512883486596` E^(-0.1` n) + 
10.` (-u[-1 + n, 0] + u[n, 0]) - 
7.071067811865475` (-u[-1 + n, 1] + u[n, 1]) - 
0.46266352733266075` u[n, 2] + 1.9629151055076721` u[n, 3] + 
7.071067811865477` (-u[-1 + n, 3] + u[n, 3])

F2 := -1.5454951288348655` E^(-0.1` n) + 
10.` (-u[-1 + n, 0] + u[n, 0]) + 
7.071067811865475` (-u[-1 + n, 1] + u[n, 1]) - 
11.047340291170295` u[n, 2] - 46.86989540377129` u[n, 3] - 
 7.0710678118654435` (-u[-1 + n, 3] + u[n, 3])

F3 := u[n, 0] - u[n, 1] + u[n, 2] - u[n, 3]

F4 := u[n, 0] + u[n, 1] + u[n, 2] + u[n, 3]


Table[Solve[{F1 == 0, F2 == 0, F3 == 0, F4 == 0}, {u[n, 0], u[n, 1], 
u[n, 2], u[n, 3]}], {n, 1, 2}]

{{{u[1, 0] -> 0.0494844, u[1, 1] -> 0.0233372, u[1, 2] -> -0.0494844, 
u[1, 3] -> -0.0233372}}, {{u[2, 0] -> 
0.0185261 + 0.789069 u[1, 0] - 0.32491 u[1, 1] + 0.32491 u[1, 3], 
u[2, 1] -> 
0.0143483 - 0.108303 u[1, 0] + 0.227981 u[1, 1] - 
 0.227981 u[1, 3], 
u[2, 2] -> -0.0185261 - 0.789069 u[1, 0] + 0.32491 u[1, 1] - 
 0.32491 u[1, 3], 
u[2, 3] -> -0.0143483 + 0.108303 u[1, 0] - 0.227981 u[1, 1] + 
 0.227981 u[1, 3]}}}
```

My question is how to make the second iteration also is scalar value \
i.e. like the first iteration .

For example :

```
u[2, 0] -> 
0.018526073525940333` + 0.7890694092812848` u[1, 0] - 
0.32491029683230876` u[1, 1] + 0.3249102968323093` u[1, 3]
```

Is there command should be added so the u[1, 0], 
    u[1, 1] and u[1, 3] not appear  in the  second  iteration but the scalar values of them?
What about the 40-iteration?

Answer (score 1):

1.You should distinguish between the Set (=) and the equal(==).

```
u[0, 0] = 0.0625`;u[0,1] = 0.031249999999999997`;u[0,2] = -0.0625`;
u[0,3] = -0.03125`;u[0,4] = -0.03125`
```

I think Set is what you need.

2.What about the the tenth iteration?

```
sol = Table[Solve[{F1 == 0, F2 == 0, F3 == 0, F4 == 0}, {u[n, 0], u[n, 1], 
     u[n, 2], u[n, 3]}], {n, 1, 10}];
Flatten@Fold[ReplaceAll[#1, #2] &, sol[[10]],Catenate@Table[sol[[i]], {i, 9, 1, -1}]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much jiaoeyushushu.

Comment: What about the the tenth iteration?

Comment: sol = Table[
    Solve[{F1 == 0, F2 == 0, F3 == 0, F4 == 0}, {u[n, 0], u[n, 1], 
     u[n, 2], u[n, 3]}], {n, 1, 20}];
     sol[[20]] /. sol[[1]]

Comment: @Khaled  I'm sorry to be so late reply to you,I have re-edit my answer,hope that can help you.

Comment: Thank you jiaoeyushu. But I could not get the result.      u[10, 0] -> 
 0.01095348600697857 + 0.6930083333219551 u[8, 0] - 
  0.4045233282254976 u[8, 1] + 0.4045233282254979 u[8, 3],  ......etc

Answer (score 0):

```
In[24]:= sol[[10]] /. sol[[9]] /. sol[[8]] /. sol[[7]] /. sol[[6]] /. 
  sol[[5]] /. sol[[4]] /. sol[[3]] /. sol[[2]] /. 
sol[[1]] // Flatten
 For the tenth iteration: 
Out[24]= {u[10, 0] -> 0.01742801369893744, 
u[10, 1] -> 0.008716037551770636, u[10, 2] -> -0.01742801369893744, 
u[10, 3] -> -0.008716037551770636}
```